# Maven: Error reading signed content

Tags: java, maven, xtext, tycho, mwe

Currently I'm investigating a maven (3.0.4) issue. I am trying to clean a project which generates java classes etc (xtext, tycho ...) and it doesn't work locally, with jenkins or in eclipse. A few days ago it works great and I did not make any changes during the last days!

Maven is downloading some necessary files and after a while he try to download e.g.  org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib_2.8.0.v201505260335.jar and it failed. He is trying a lot more mirror and the download are failing too.

Maven said:

```
"Retry another mirror": ["Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib,2.8.0.v201505260335.": ["Error reading signed content:D:\cygwin64\tmp\signatureFile7029196355039391088.jar"]
```

But I think the problem here is not the download. He cannot process the downloaded file, because the file e.g. signatureFile7029196355039391088.jar exists and the file size is the same as on the server where I have downloaded it from.

Because the stacktrace is a bit long and the messages are repeating for every mirror, here the stacktrace extract:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "Messages while trying children repositories.": ["Messages while trying children repositories.": ["Messages while trying children repositories.": ["Messages while trying children repositories.": ["": ["Multiple problems occurred while downloading.": ["Failed to transfer artifact packed: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime,2.8.0.v201505260335.":["Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib,2.8.0.v201505260335.": ["Error reading signed content:D:\cygwin64\tmp\signatureFile7029196355039391088.jar"]]]]]]]]]
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.P2ArtifactDownloadTool.downloadArtifactsToLocalMavenRepository(P2ArtifactDownloadTool.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformImpl.downloadArtifacts(TargetPlatformImpl.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:61)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        ... 11 more
```

As I said, the same behaviour on different environments: IDE, local (cygwin) and unix (jenkins).

Any ideas?

Kind Regards